# Display text/image while Vuforia plane finder is detecting surface

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am developing a game with Vuforia in Unity.
What I am attempting to do is to display a Plane/Canvas/Image while vuforia is detecting the surface so my users will not feel lost while Vuforia is scanning.
But the problem is i've looked into the only 2 available scripts that i can find,

```
DefaultTrackableEventHandler.cs
```

and

```
DefaultInitializationErrorHandler
```

but I could not pin point the script where it initialize the detection.

So my request is to ask if anyone know which part of the code does Vuforia initialize the scan so i can customise it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are using ground plane since you have written " detecting the surface "
The plane finder behavior script is responsible for "scanning" and finding horizontal surfaces. What you can do is check vuforia samples from asset store and there you can see this script is doing Hit tests constantly to find positions on the detected surfaces. Therefore, as long as this on Automatic Hit Test is called, it means your device has found a surface and performing hits towards your indicator.

[image]

In this example `HandleAutomaticHitTest` attached to PlaneManager is called every time Automatic Hit Test is called. You can modify this `HandleAutomaticHitTest` script to achieve what you wanted.
One last note i am not 100% sure but the scanning probably starts when the positional device tracker is started or vuforia started.

Answer (score 0):

What we did was display an "instruction panel" that filled the entire screen when the scene loaded. It allowed the device to detect the environment while the user read the instructions. Then we just had an "Ok" button at the bottom that disabled the panel when clicked, thus revealing the AR experience. See attached screenshot. [Instruction Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDQE0.jpg)

Comment: i am actually doing what you've mentioned too, but i think its not good enough, scanning can still take some time after they've closed the instruction panel and users might still feel lost even though i've explicitly given them the instruction.

Comment: That's odd. I'm assuming your environment is well lit? I never have any problems getting the scene detected while the user reads the instructions.